# Is it possible to change a Page to branch?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Is it possible to change the `Template` of a page to `Branch Template`? When I try in Sitecore 7.0 UI it gives a error message stating to "Select a Template".

Is there any other way to change an Item's Template to be a Branch Template?

Comment: Hum... what are you trying to achieve, exactly?   A branch is more like a "preconfigured set of items based on a template/set of templates" - not something an actual content item can be directly based on.

Comment: I have some pages in sitecore. We are thinking of changing the template of the page to a new template and also want some folders to get created automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just substitute a template of an item with a branch template. You might be probably confused by mutual term **template** they both use and the fact the both exist undet /sitecore/templates node, however they are absolutely different in their internals.

Branch templates are just template sub-nodes that are being copied in instantiation. You may still use tokens and they would apply for every single item in a branch. But each of the items from a branch would still origin from certain individual template.

[image]

Thus, you *cannot* just do **Configure** --> **Change** on an item and then select a branch template instead of ordinary template, that's why Branches node is highlighted with grey color and even if you try to select any - sitecore will tell you "please select a template".

[image]

What you can do is just to re-create your item from branch template and (assuming) previous item now becomes a part of your branch - you may simply manually copy all the presentation details. However an ID of that item would differ with an ID of initial item (unless you manually replace original item into a branch instantiated)

I previously wrote an article on how to **copy presentation detail manually** between items, it will help you with your case:

http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/copying-presentation-details-manually

Comment: Don't forget to move any existing child items to the new item as well. And beware of possible conflicting children (e.g. existing item with the same name as a child in the branch).

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer - No

Long Answer -

As the `Branch Template` its self is not technically a `Template`, its a `Branch` it can't be used as a `Template`. The `Items` the branch contains aren't `Templates` themselves either. They are `Items` based on a `Template`.

As none of these `Items` are `Templates` you can not change the `Template` of an `Item` to one of the Items in your `Branch`.

If you need the Item to identified as created from a Branch in the `Created Form` property of the Item you will need to create a new Item via the Branch and copy its content and presentation to it.

I have confirmed this is still the case in Sitecore 8.